# TFS custom bug entry page for non technical users?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2012

To help my company better adopt using TFS i'd like to see if a custom web page could be made so the end user has no idea they're entering a bug into TFS.  They find the TFS2012 web based GUI confusing.  They are business users and able to write out a problem in a web app, the reproduction steps and expected result but they always forget to set certain fields which makes their entries not show up in my query.

I figured creating a custom web page that inserts the bug into TFS would help.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a web page which uses TFS API to create a bug. Please see below link which has sample code to create bugs using API.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3280.tfs-2010-api-create-workitems-bugs.aspx